# Можно ли написать "близко мало"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

"Немного жаль, что близко мало было полностью распустившихся цветов."

Answer (score 3):

Понять можно (видимо, хотелось, подойдя к краю клумбы, нарвать приличный букет), но фразу стоит немного "причесать":

`Жаль, но полностью распустившихся цветов вблизи было маловато.`

(Пришлось протоптать путь к центру клумбы.)

Answer (score 2):

Немного жаль, что вблизи было мало полностью распустившихся цветов.

Предложение должно состоять **из двух частей** (предмет - сообщение о предмете), **разделенных условной паузой**:

Вблизи было мало - (чего?) полностью распустившихся цветов.

Answer (score 1):

Ни в коем случае. Смысл ускользает, я так с третьего раза понял. И то не факт, что правильно.

Правда, возможно, что я просто тупой. Подождите других ответов.

Comment: От меня тоже ускользнул.

Answer (score 0):

Поддерживаю: понять можно, но приходится вчитываться несколько раз. Лучше перефразировать.